# Performing a Hadamard product with SymPy

Tags: sympy

I'm using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to do linear algebra. I want to perform an element-wise multiplication ([Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29)) on two matricies.

For example,

```python
sympy.MatrixSymbol('X', 4, 3) [operator/method] sympy.MatrixSymbol('W', 4, 3)
```

would give

```
[[X[0,0]*W[0,0], X[0,1]*W[0,1], ...],[X[1,0]*W[1,0], X[1,1]*W[1,1], ...]]
```

But it seems that there isn't a method for it. Is there any way to perform an element-wise multiplication with SymPy?

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is a function in SymPy that can do element-wise multiplication (Hadamard product). As per their documentation of SymPy 0.7.6 the function is:

**multiply_elementwise(b)**

Returns the Hadamard product (elementwise product) of A and B.

Example:

```
>>> from sympy.matrices import Matrix
>>> A = Matrix([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
>>> B = Matrix([[1, 10, 100], [100, 10, 1]])
>>> A.multiply_elementwise(B)
Matrix([
[  0, 10, 200],
[300, 40,   5]])
```

**Update:** For element-wise multiplication of `MatrixSymbols` use the following function:

**HadamardProduct(A, B)**

For Example:

```
>>> from sympy import HadamardProduct
>>> A = MatrixSymbol('A', m, n)
>>> B = MatrixSymbol('B', m, n)
>>>print(HadamardProduct(A,B))
A.*B
```

Comment: Your A, B are not a MatrixSymbol.. I want to do elmentwise_multiplication with MatrixSymbol, not Matrix